# Changing TFS Service account

Tags: sql-server, team-foundation-server

I have an installation of TFS that was installed incorrectly and the account that the services run under is a developers account!  Not great.

I have created a domain account called TFSService to run TFS under and I am going to change the account using the "Change Account" option in for the "Application Teir" in TFS but I wandered if there are any permissions that I need to apply to the databases on the database server (which is a separate machine)?  Or is this something that TFS takes care of it's self using the current account?

I don't want to apply permissions and have TFS fail in the event it tried to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do anything with permissions yourself. TFS does it all for you when you use the Change account option in the TFS admin console.

Here is the relevant page on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb552178.aspx

Look at "To use the administration console to change the service account" under the section, "Assigning a Different Account as the Service Account."